# Access main application class in Quarkus extension

Tags: quarkus

I have a main Quarkus application with an EventBus which publishes a custom `MyEvent` class, and a Quarkus extension designed for the main application with a listener for these events.

My problem is : **the extension does not know the `MyEvent` class**, so it cannot read the events as anything else than basic `Object`. I need to access the `MyEvent` attributes values in the extension. Is there a way to achieve that ?

I tried redefining the `MyEvent` class in the extension (`MyExtEvent`) for brutal casting, but it did obviously not work.

Simplified main app code :

MyEvent :

```
public class MyEvent {
    private String id;
    private String data;

    public MyEvent() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Service :

```
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.eventbus.EventBus;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyServiceBean implements MyService {
    @Inject
    EventBus bus;

    public void notify(MyEvent event) {
        bus.publish("audit", event);
    }
}
```

Simplified extension code :

MyExtEvent :

```
public class MyExtEvent {
    private String id;
    private String data;

    public MyExtEvent() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Listener :

```
import io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@RequestScoped
public class EventsListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EventsListener.class.getName());

    @ConsumeEvent(value = "audit")
    public void consume(Object oevent) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Event received : " + oevent.toString());
        MyExtEvent event = (MyExtEvent) oevent;
        // Do stuff with "id" and "data" fields
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Event id : " + event.getId());
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Event data : " + event.getData());
    }
}
```

Casting exception received after the logging line :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class <main app path>.MyEvent cannot be cast to class <extension path>.MyExtEvent (<main app path>.MyEvent is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @79d9214d; <extension path>.MyExtEvent is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @3c22fc4c)
```

Comment: Why not define an interface in the extension code and have the application implement that?

Comment: @geoand Because the extension is supposed to be non-invasive towards the main app. (In short, the main app is a freeware and the extension is purchasable.) The main app should be able to compile without the extension...

Comment: Understood, but then why not ship the types as a separate dependency that will be included by both the application and the extension?